# How do I make the output-large data file-concise matlab

Tags: matlab, output

I have a large data input file (50,000 lines); the answers from the data are okay-- min, max, mean, std,-- but I need for the output to come out in a table. I have the code for the solar minimum and the solar maximum but how do I get them to be displayed side-by-side in a helpful way? Here's my code to display the results, but how do I manipulate the results side-by-side, for each year?

```
%this is the solar maximum year
N = 100;
solarmax = fopen('ACE_magswe_64sec_2000.txt','r+');
formatSpec = '%*d %*d %*d %*d %*f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f';

minNp = [];
maxNp = [];
meanNp = [];
stdNp = [];

minTp = [];
maxTp = [];
meanTp = [];
stdTp = [];

minVx = [];
maxVx = [];
meanVx = [];
stdVx = [];

minVy = [];
maxVy = [];
meanVy = [];
stdVy = [];

minVz = [];
maxVz = [];
meanVz = [];
stdVz = [];

minBx = [];
maxBx = [];
meanBx = [];
stdBx = [];

minBy = [];
maxBy = [];
meanBy = [];
stdBy = [];

minBz = [];
maxBz = [];
meanBz = [];
stdBz = [];


while ~feof(solarmax)
    C = textscan(solarmax,formatSpec,N,'HeaderLines',2,'Delimiter','\t');
    Np = cell2mat(C(:,1)); 
    Tp = cell2mat(C(:,2));
    Vx = cell2mat(C(:,3));
    Vy = cell2mat(C(:,4));
    Vz = cell2mat(C(:,5));
    Bx = cell2mat(C(:,6));
    By = cell2mat(C(:,7));
    Bz = cell2mat(C(:,8));


    Np(Np == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Tp(Tp == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Vx(Vx == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Vy(Vy == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Vz(Vz == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Bx(Bx == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    By(By == -9999.90039) = NaN;
    Bz(Bz == -9999.90039) = NaN;

    minNp(end+1) = min(Np);
    maxNp(end+1) = max(Np);
    meanNp(end+1) = mean(Np);
    stdNp(end+1) = std(Np);

    minTp(end+1) = min(Tp);
    maxTp(end+1) = max(Tp);
    meanTp(end+1) = mean(Tp);
    stdTp(end+1) = std(Tp);

    minVx(end+1) = min(Vx);
    maxVx(end+1) = max(Vx);
    meanVx(end+1) = mean(Vx);
    stdVx(end+1) = std(Vx);

    minVy(end+1) = min(Vy);
    maxVy(end+1) = min(Vy);
    meanVy(end+1) = mean(Vy);
    stdVy(end+1) = std(Vy);

    minVz(end+1) = min(Vz);
    maxVz(end+1) = max(Vz);
    meanVz(end+1) = mean(Vz);
    stdVz(end+1) = std(Vz);

    minBx(end+1) = min(Bx);
    maxBx(end+1) = max(Bx);
    meanBx(end+1) = mean(Bx);
    stdBx(end+1) = std(Bx);

    minBy(end+1) = min(By);
    maxBy(end+1) = max(By);
    meanBy(end+1) = mean(By);
    stdBy(end+1) = std(By);

    minBz(end+1) = min(Bz);
    maxBz(end+1) = max(Bz);
    meanBz(end+1) = mean(Bz);
    stdBz(end+1) = std(Bz);

end
fclose(solarmax);

nanmin(minNp);
nanmax(maxNp);
nanmean(meanNp);
nanstd(stdNp);

nanmin(minTp);
nanmax(maxTp);
nanmean(meanTp);
nanstd(stdTp);

nanmin(minVx);
nanmax(maxVx);
nanmean(meanVx);
nanstd(stdVx);

nanmin(minVy);
nanmax(maxVy);
nanmean(meanVy);
nanstd(stdVy);

nanmin(minVz);
nanmax(maxVz);
nanmean(meanVz);
nanstd(stdVz);

nanmin(minBx);
nanmax(maxBx);
nanmean(meanBx);
nanstd(stdBx);

nanmin(minBy);
nanmax(maxBy);
nanmean(meanBy);
nanstd(stdBy);

nanmin(minBz);
nanmax(maxBz);
nanmean(meanBz);
nanstd(stdBz);


%this is the solar minimum year
N = 100;
solarmin = fopen('ACE_magswe_64sec_2008.txt','r+');
formatSpec = '%*d %*d %*d %*d %*f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f';

minNp1 = [];
maxNp1 = [];
meanNp1 = [];
stdNp1 = [];

minTp1 = [];
maxTp1 = [];
meanTp1 = [];
stdTp1 = [];

minVx1 = [];
maxVx1 = [];
meanVx1 = [];
stdVx1 = [];

minVy1 = [];
maxVy1 = [];
meanVy1 = [];
stdVy1 = [];

minVz1 = [];
maxVz1 = [];
meanVz1 = [];
stdVz1 = [];

minBx1 = [];
maxBx1 = [];
meanBx1 = [];
stdBx1 = [];

minBy1 = [];
maxBy1 = [];
meanBy1 = [];
stdBy1 = [];

minBz1 = [];
maxBz1 = [];
meanBz1 = [];
stdBz1 = [];


while ~feof(solarmin)
    B = textscan(solarmin,formatSpec,N,'HeaderLines',2,'Delimiter','\t');
    Np1 = cell2mat(B(:,1)); 
    Tp1 = cell2mat(B(:,2));
    Vx1 = cell2mat(B(:,3));
    Vy1 = cell2mat(B(:,4));
    Vz1 = cell2mat(B(:,5));
    Bx1 = cell2mat(B(:,6));
    By1 = cell2mat(B(:,7));
    Bz1 = cell2mat(B(:,8));

    Np1(Np1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Tp1(Tp1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Vx1(Vx1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Vy1(Vy1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Vz1(Vz1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Bx1(Bx1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    By1(By1 == -9999.90) = NaN;
    Bz1(Bz1 == -9999.90) = NaN;

    minNp1(end+1) = min(Np1);
    maxNp1(end+1) = max(Np1);
    meanNp1(end+1) = mean(Np1);
    stdNp1(end+1) = std(Np1);

    minTp1(end+1) = min(Tp1);
    maxTp1(end+1) = max(Tp1);
    meanTp1(end+1) = mean(Tp1);
    stdTp1(end+1) = std(Tp1);

    minVx1(end+1) = min(Vx1);
    maxVx1(end+1) = max(Vx1);
    meanVx1(end+1) = mean(Vx1);
    stdVx1(end+1) = std(Vx1);

    minVy1(end+1) = min(Vy1);
    maxVy1(end+1) = max(Vy1);
    meanVy1(end+1) = mean(Vy1);
    stdVy1(end+1) = std(Vy1);

    minVz1(end+1) = min(Vz1);
    maxVz1(end+1) = max(Vz1);
    meanVz1(end+1) = mean(Vz1);
    stdVz1(end+1) = std(Vz1);

    minBx1(end+1) = min(Bx1);
    maxBx1(end+1) = max(Bx1);
    meanBx1(end+1) = mean(Bx1);
    stdBx1(end+1) = std(Bx1);

    minBy1(end+1) = min(By1);
    maxBy1(end+1) = max(By1);
    meanBy1(end+1) = mean(By1);
    stdBy1(end+1) = std(By1);

    minBz1(end+1) = min(Bz1);
    maxBz1(end+1) = max(Bz1);
    meanBz1(end+1) = mean(Bz1);
    stdBz1(end+1) = std(Bz1);


end
fclose(solarmin);

nanmin(minNp1);
nanmax(maxNp1);
nanmean(meanNp1);
nanstd(stdNp1);

nanmin(minTp1);
nanmax(maxTp1);
nanmean(meanTp1);
nanstd(stdTp1);

nanmin(minVx1);
nanmax(maxVx1);
nanmean(meanVx1);
nanstd(stdVx1);

nanmin(minVy1);
nanmax(maxVy1);
nanmean(meanVy1);
nanstd(stdVy1);

nanmin(minVz1);
nanmax(maxVz1);
nanmean(meanVz1);
nanstd(stdVz1);

nanmin(minBx1);
nanmax(maxBx1);
nanmean(meanBx1);
nanstd(stdBx1);

nanmin(minBy1);
nanmax(maxBy1);
nanmean(meanBy1);
nanstd(stdBy1);

nanmin(minBz1);
nanmax(maxBz1);
nanmean(meanBz1);
nanstd(stdBz1);
```

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you give us an example of the output you want?

Comment: Use `fprintf` in a `for` loop. In each line, print one solar minimum and one solar maximum, side by side.

Comment: Don't really understand what you need, but at first glance you have WAY too many variables, leading to huge amounts of duplicated code. Try storing everything in 1 or a few variables.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating many arrays, just create one.

For example,

```
minSolar = [];
maxSolar = [];
meanSolar = [];
stdSolar = [];

minSolar(end+1,:) = [min(Np) min(Tp) min(Vx)  min(Vy) min(Vz)];
maxSolar(end+1,:) = [max(Np) max(Tp) max(Vx)  max(Vy) max(Vz)];
```